# Preventing touch passing from UIControl to ParentView

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have created a custom control for Uber like OTP TextField. I want to consume the touch in my control and not let it propagate through the UIResponder Chain. So I have overridden the methods as described in  [apple documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621142-touchesbegan)

```
extension BVAPasswordTextField {
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>,  with event: UIEvent?) {
   becomeFirstResponder()
  }

  override func touchesMoved(Set<UITouch>, with: UIEvent?) {

}

override func touchesEnded(Set<UITouch>, with: UIEvent?) {

}

override func touchesCancelled(Set<UITouch>, with: UIEvent?) {

 }

override func touchesEstimatedPropertiesUpdated(Set<UITouch>) {

  }
}
```

Now in some view controller I want to dismiss the keyboard when the user taps anywhere outside my custom control.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tapGestureRecogniser = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.backgroundTapped))
    tapGestureRecogniser.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecogniser)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@objc func backgroundTapped() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

But whenever I tap on the textfield **backgroundTapped** also gets called.

**Note:-** *It is a control where based on enum values you can create different UI Components for taking input. So this control can be shared among the whole team... I won't be the only guy using it.... So I want it to behave exactly like UITextfield in touch scenario*

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the tap gesture using `UITapGestureRecognizerDelegate`. It allows you to decide whether or not gesture should begin. In your case, it should be done basing on the location of the touch.

```
extension ViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        let location = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.view)
        // return true is location of touch is outside our textField
        return !textField.frame.contains(location)
    }
}
```

Just make sure you've set a `delegate` for your gesture at `viewDidLoad`

```
tapGestureRecogniser.delegate = self
```

**UPDATE**

If I got your setup right, you have a view and some subviews that are used for input. And you want to `resignFirstResponder` when this `super-view` is touched. In that case you can use `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` like that

```
func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    let location = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.view)
    for subview in self.view.subviews {
        if subview.frame.contains(location) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

In my opinion, if you want to handle some `view` interaction in a specific way, you need to do it using that specific `view`. And what you're doing now feels like trying to change behavior on one `view`, using **another** view.

Comment: I know this...But it is a control where based on enum values you can create different UI Components for taking input. So this control can be shared among the whole team... I won't be the only guy using it.... So I want it to behave exactly like UITextfield in touch scenario..

Comment: @KeshavRaj I've updated my answer. Probably I didn't get your problem right. But I've tried to explain my point of view.

Comment: I want this control to be used in any view controller without any specific coding for gestureRecognizerShouldBegin..... If I go by delegate approach then wherever I am using it , owner of this control needs to implement this delegate method ....That is not the case with UITextField ..... So I searched the AppleDocumentation and found the above link (specified in question) to prevent touch event from travelling up in the UIResponder chain hierarchy....But that is not working..... Hope I am clear enough now

Comment: Then why don't you just add a gestureRecognizer onto your control view?

Comment: https://github.com/keshavRaj/BVAotpTextField
Checkout what I am trying to achieve by giving the image or giving border type values and playing with other properties.....So it can be used by multiple people ...

Comment: How adding gesture recognizer in my control would help?? Please elaborate..

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to prevent the touches in this control moving up in the responder chain.